# Why is flash player update package password protected?

Tags: windows, virus, flash, anti-virus

I noticed this error while scanning the file "install_flashplayer11x32au_mssd_aaa_aih.exe":

"SOME FILES COULD NOT BE SCANNED"

And then I looked through the .exe file with 7zip and saw that the package is indeed password protected, thus I am unable to open any files in it.

Why is this, are they trying to ship a virus to my computer by preventing my virus scanner from scanning the package?

Comment: It shouldn't be.  The one from Adobe's website is not.

Comment: And submit the file to one of the major meta-scanners (VirusTotal.com or metascan-online.com or Jotti.org) so file makes its way to various malware repositories if necessary.

Comment: @BillR, how could those scan the file if its pw-protected? will they execute it, and somehow get the pw and then scan it? seems like someone already scanned this file on virustotal.com.

Comment: @Rookie - Just out of curiosity, did VT say .exe was clean?  Perhaps I misunderstood.  I (mis?)interpreted this as the .exe included _some_ protected files.  A common malware technique is to modify a standard installer to both install/upgrade the good software and also hidden malware.  The core malware itself may be encrypted, named randomly, etc. but the installer has to have a way to run it that the AVs can look for (signature or behavior, although the latter is quite limited in the meta-scanners AFAIK).

Comment: @BillR, yes. somehow i didnt trust that since it was pw protected file; what if they just ignore it and dont scan?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn’t always like this. In the past, Flash was shipped in an unprotected SFX file, so you could indeed extract the contents and manually install it instead of being forced to use the installer.

I personally dislike installers and prefer to manually install everything because I have better control over what happens to my system that way. As such, I used to manually extract the files, put them where I want, and register them with the system as needed.

Unfortunately big companies tend not to like letting users doing things for themselves and will try to “protect” users by automating everything for them (whether needed or not). Protecting the files is one way that they do this. Now you *must* use the installer to install Flash. (Technically you don’t; you can still install it in a VM while monitoring the changes it makes to the system, then extract the files and registry entries, and copy them to the main system.)

Also notice that your installer is only ~2MB instead of the 15MB+ that it should be. This is because it is not even the full package; it’s only only a “web-installer” which analyzes your system and downloads whatever is necessary to install Flash. You may wonder why the web-installers need to analyze your system if the page where you download them from already asks you to determine what version you want. It’s likely because they want to check if you already have the latest version(s) of file(s) in order to reduce the bandwidth required to transfer the files to you (sending the whole installer might be a waste of bandwidth—even though you specifically asked for it)—I remember when the *full* installer was ~2MB.

The latest versions of the full, offline, standalone installer for [IE](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player_ax.exe) and [other browsers](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player.exe) are available. Unfortunately, you’re not much better off with those because while they actually contain the installation files, they are not merely “zipped”; they are packed in with a proprietary system so you still need to run the installer. But they come directly from Adobe’s systems, so at least they’re not infected (and if they are, you can sue them—well, you *could* have sued them if they hadn’t snuck in all kinds of “we’re not responsible for squat” type of language in the EULA).

You can even get the latest version for [IE](http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/win/install_flash_player_11_active_x.msi) and [other browsers](http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/win/install_flash_player_11_plugin.msi) in Windows installer form. Unfortunately these are just the regular executable installers packed in an `.msi` file which when run, merely extracts the regular executable installer and runs it, so don’t expect to be able to extract the files from these either.